# Why isn't the navigationItem.titleView working?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to put in an UIButton in the center of the navigation bar. Based on the document, it appears I need to set title view, and make sure the leftBarButtonItem is nil. But it is not work for me. Here is the code.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setTitle:@"List" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:btn];
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you examine your button, you'll find that by using the convenience method to initialize it you are left with a 0x0 button that is positioned at 0,0 within the bounds of the view it is being added to. Before doing this, you must define the contents of the `frame` property of the button.  See the code below:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, kCustomButtonHeight);
[btn setTitle:@"list" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.titleView = btn;
```

Comment: Still, btn is not clickable.

Answer (score 16):

In my case I was trying to set it in a child view controller, this fixed it

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Answer (score 7):

The view of the navigationItem is set, by default, to nil.

You need to use

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = btn;
```